# Is there a way to simplify interval input to allow filling one single endpoint?

Tags: forms, input

Let’s say I want users to fill an event start and end dates. If the event lasts one day then these are the same, and it feels redundant to input the same date twice.

However, I can’t imagine how a form could permit filling only one date in a simple and intuitive way.

---

Thanks everyone for your feedback. It seems everyone agrees automatically filling the end interval by default is good UX, so I’ll give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a matter of fact, this is quite common. You only fill in the initial date and then leave the end date as is. Let's consider Google Meet.

[image]

Here, it gets the current date and the next available time slot on round hours.

If I change to another initial date:

[image]

Note how the end date changed automatically to the same initial date (which makes sense since you'll rarely have a meet lasting days, unless it starts late at night).

**Working with hours**

Finally, you have the option for "All day," which doesn't apply to your date case but may be useful if you also have a similar issue with hours, or hours are not important (event lasts all day but users can arrive whenever they want).

[image]

## Bottom line

Either way, the important part is that users don't need to add an end date, only the start date. And users have the chance to enter an end date only if specifically needed.

Comment: Thanks for a real-life example

Answer (score 2):

One option: When the user first fills in the blank dates, they will probably do the start date first. When they do, shadow-fill the end date with the same value. They can then change it if they want.

Another option: Use a single date picker widget that has a range, such as [this one](https://www.daterangepicker.com/). Then choosing the same date twice means clicking twice in the same spot and is no longer laborious.

Third option: Use a checkbox called "One-day event" or similar to control whether you present an input for the end date. (Similar to how on LinkedIn you can add employment from a start date to an end date, but if you check "I am currently employed here", it removes the end date option.)

All of these can be found in the wild.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest  2 options:

1. One date input + checkbox (marked) saying “same date”. When user unselects the checkbox, another date input is added
2. Two date inputs, when user types in the date, the other input updated automatically with the same date. in case the user need to change it, he can do that manually